# Как изменить угол в зависимости от направления движения объекта в pygame

Tags: python, математика, разработка-игр, pygame

Суть такова: есть 2D пространство, в котором также имеется объект, в моем случае ракета. Она перемещается по этому пространству в разных направлениях, и постоянно меняет направление движения. То есть меняются только ее координаты. Мне требуется добиться того, чтобы при определенном направлении движения ракеты, она поворачивалась передней частью по вектору движения. Было бы идеально, если бы я понял как изменить угол ее поворота как сразу (мгновенно), так и постепенно, то есть плавно. Вот, что у меня пока что имеется:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

size = width, height = (1600, 900)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 1440


def load_image(name):
    fullname = 'data'+'/'+name
    try:
        if name[-2:] == 'jpg':
            image = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
        else:
            image = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert_alpha()
    except:
        print('Cannot load image: ', name)
        raise SystemExit()
    return image


class Zone(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    image = load_image("zone.png")

    def __init__(self, x, y, number):
        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        self.image = Zone.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        #self.vx = random.randint(0, 0)
        #self.vy = random.randrange(0, 0)
        self.add(number)


class Rocket(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    image = load_image("rocket.png")

    def __init__(self, x, y, number):
        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        self.image = Rocket.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vx = random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.vy = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.add(number)

    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.vx, self.vy)
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, horizontal_borders):
            self.vy = -self.vy
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, vertical_borders):
            self.vx = -self.vx


class Border(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        super().__init__(all_sprites)
        if x1 == x2:
            self.add(vertical_borders)
            self.image = pygame.Surface([1, y2 - y1])
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 1, y2 - y1)
        else:
            self.add(horizontal_borders)
            self.image = pygame.Surface([x2 - x1, 1])
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, 1)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

horizontal_borders = pygame.sprite.Group()
vertical_borders = pygame.sprite.Group()
number1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
number2 = pygame.sprite.Group()

Border(5, 5, width - 5, 5)
Border(5, height - 5, width - 5, height - 5)
Border(5, 5, 5, height - 5)
Border(width - 5, 5, width - 5, height - 5)

Rocket1 = Rocket(100, 100, number1)
Zone1 = Zone(300, 400, number2)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for sprite in all_sprites:
        sprite.update()

    if (Rocket1.rect.x - Zone1.rect.x) ** 2 + (Rocket1.rect.y - Zone1.rect.y) ** 2 <= 50 ** 2:
        Rocket1.vx, Rocket1.vy = 0, 0

    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

PS Я уже сталкивался с подобной задачей, но там был несколько иной смысл, там необходимо было наоборот изменять координаты объекта, зная угол его поворота. Там я быстро нагуглил ответ, а здесь немного застрял, потому что не силен в математике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть вектор движения `(vx, vy)`. Вот в соответствие с ним и приводите угол поворота ракеты (я не вижу, чтобы он вообще присутствовал).

Проще всего иметь нормализованный вектор  `(ux, uy)` - его компоненты суть косинус и синус угла направления

```
v = sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)
ux = vx / v
uy = vy / v
```

Если по какой-то причине нужен сам угол:

```
angle = atan2(vy, vx)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось :)